# SuperCollider: What's the command to make [ [1,2], [3,4] ] become [1,2,3,4]?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, supercollider

What's the command to make [ [1,2], [3,4] ] become [1,2,3,4] ?

*(asked on behalf of someone else)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.flat` message is what you're after:

`[[1,2],[3,4]].flat`

there's also `.flatten` which gives the same result in this case (but `.flatten` only flattens one "level" whereas `.flat` will flatten all the way down to a fully-flat array)